# Scraping hyperlink data from within a URL using a pre-made data web scraper?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href, tablerow, data-science

I'm using a web scraper based on BeautifulSoup to get table data and hyperlinks within the table data, but I am not getting the URL extensions that I want. Here is the intructional page with the pre-made script: http://savvastjortjoglou.com/nfl-draft.html (also see my pasted matching code below).

Although the person who did this pre-made script got all of the data he needed, when I perform the same scraping it fails to successfully scrape the URL extensions that I need for each player (example: for Bubby Smith, I need to scrape the '/players/S/SmitBu00.htm' line).

It appears that my table rows contain the data I need,but then my code that's supposed to read in the table rows is not successfully finding the URL extensions.

Why is my scraper not getting the player's URL extension?

```
# The url we will be scraping
url_1967 = "http://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/1967/draft.htm"

# get the html
html = urlopen(url_1967)

# create the BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

# Extract the necessary values for the column headers from the table
# and store them as a list
column_headers = [th.getText() for th in 
                  soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[1].findAll('th')]

# Add the two additional column headers for the player links
column_headers.extend(["Player_NFL_Link", "Player_NCAA_Link"])

# The data is found within the table rows of the element with id=draft
# We want the elements from the 3rd row and on
table_rows = soup.select("#drafts tr")[2:] 

def extract_player_data(table_rows):
    """
    Extract and return the the desired information from the td elements within
    the table rows.
    """
# create the empty list to store the player data
player_data = []

for row in table_rows:  # for each row do the following

    # Get the text for each table data (td) element in the row
    # Some player names end with ' HOF', if they do, get the text excluding
    # those last 4 characters,
    # otherwise get all the text data from the table data
    player_list = [td.get_text()[:-4] if td.get_text().endswith(" HOF") 
                   else td.get_text() for td in row.find_all("td")]

    # there are some empty table rows, which are the repeated 
    # column headers in the table
    # we skip over those rows and and continue the for loop
    if not player_list:
        continue

    # Extracting the player links
    # Instead of a list we create a dictionary, this way we can easily
    # match the player name with their pfr url
    # For all "a" elements in the row, get the text
    # NOTE: Same " HOF" text issue as the player_list above
    links_dict = {(link.get_text()[:-4]   # exclude the last 4 characters
                   if link.get_text().endswith(" HOF")  # if they are " HOF"
                   # else get all text, set thet as the dictionary key 
                   # and set the url as the value
                   else link.get_text()) : link["href"] 
                   for link in row.find_all("a", href=True)}

    # The data we want from the dictionary can be extracted using the
    # player's name, which returns us their pfr url, and "College Stats"
    # which returns us their college stats page

    # add the link associated to the player's pro-football-reference page, 
    # or en empty string if there is no link
    player_list.append(links_dict.get(player_list[3], ""))

    # add the link for the player's college stats or an empty string
    # if ther is no link
    player_list.append(links_dict.get("College Stats", ""))

    # Now append the data to list of data
    player_data.append(player_list)

# extract the data we want
list_data_1967 = extract_player_data(table_rows)
```

Comment: are you getting any exception? try printing our link in tour script to see what is happening

Comment: There is no error or exception. The scraper mostly works. However, today something strange happened. For a moment while I was doing some editing, I got the data for this column for some rows (about half of them), but not all rows. But when I tried to replicate this, it wouldn't work.

Now it is back to not working at all. I am stumped.